# Strange array behavior in Java

Tags: java, arrays

This is a simple array declaration and initialization.

```
  int arr[] = new int[10];

    for(int i = 0; i<arr.length; i++){

    arr[i] = i;
    }
```

This

```
System.out.println(arr[000001]);
```

to

```
System.out.println(arr[000007]);
```

prints out the correct values but anything above `8`

```
System.out.println(arr[000008]);
```

produces a `java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code`

Why does this happen?

Comment: Never saw that exception in my life. In my IDE it just doesn't compile.

Comment: Allright, it is NetBeans stuff. I was surprised of that exception being thrown when running an already compiled application!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This has nothing to do with arrays; integers starting with the digit `0` are octal (base 8). The legal octal digits are 0-7, so that `08` (or `00000008`) are invalid octal integer literals. The correct octal for `8` is `010`.

Answer (score 6):

It's because the 0's in front of your index make Java think you're using the octal numbering system.

Answer (score 5):

It has nothing to do with arrays.

Integer literals that start with a `0` are [expected to be](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/lexical.html#3.10.1) [octal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octal) numerals.

Therefore, if you have any diggit bigger than `7` (i.e. `8` or `9`) in there, then it won't compile.

Also: you only get an `Exception` because your IDE allows you to execute code that doesn't compile. That's a **very bad** idea, you should look at the compiler error it produces instead (it will probably have much more information than the message you posted).

Answer (score 4):

It happens because 000001 , 000007, 000008 is [octal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octal) notation.  Integer literals starting with 0 is treated as octal. However there is no such thing as 000008 in a base 8 numeral system (octal).

(Though, I would have expected that to fail during compile time, not runtime)